# Unable to get value Textbox by id in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have text boxes and it has values let say. I am calling my javascript method on one of textbox 'onblur'. my function is:

```
function CalculateExpectedProductPrice() {
  alert("hi i called");
  var originalPrice = document.getElementById('hdnSelectedProductPrice').value;

  var numberOfLicenses = document.getElementById('txtNumberOfLicense').value;
  var enteredAmount = document.getElementById('txtAmount').value;

  alert(originalPrice);
  alert(numberOfLicenses);
  alert(enteredAmount);

}
```

i am getting alert message as ""hi i called". but not further.

But some i am not getting values of these controls.

****Edited:****  My HTML is :

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnSelectedProductPrice" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" runat="server" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtNumberOfLicense" runat="server" Width="35px" ></asp:TextBox>
   </ContentTemplate>
   <Triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtNumberOfLicense" EventName="" />
   </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Will there any impact master-content page . because script is in content page and html also on same content page.Also let me know you, I am using wizard control where as all these controls are resides on second step of wizard. will that make any impact ?

**Edited:**

I think wizard control making here matter. As i started my firebug and review the generated html it assign the Id dynamically to those controls which are inside the wizard. thats why javascript unable to find the expected control .
eg for txtAmount text box which is inside the wizard control getting name as :

```
ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Wizard1_txtAmount
```

but certainly i would not prefer to use this generated Id. So is there any remedy to find control inside the wizard control and get - set values ?

Comment: yes please review the question again. I have added my HTML. and may i ask why -1 here ? since all things are right though unable to get value ...so what is my fault ?

Comment: i did before this so many times. but now some how i am unable to find any mistake here. can you guys please help me to sort out this?

Answer (score 4):

get id of the control as shown below

```
var enteredAmount = document.getElementById('<%=txtAmount.ClientId%>').value;
```

Comment: but only if the control has runat="server" declared!

Comment: why would you have an ASP.NET control on your page without runat="server"? Or am I being stupid?

Comment: I tried this but not getting any output yet. see question again

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to say for certain with your not having quoted your HTML (!), but the usual reason for this is confusion between the `id` and `name` attributes. `document.getElementById` works with the `id` attribute, but people tend to think it works with the `name` on input fields, which it doesn't (except for on IE, where `getElementById` [is broken](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/by-any-other-name-would-smell-as-sweet.html)).

(The other thing to remember is that `id` values **must** be unique on the entire page, but looking at the IDs you quoted, I suspect you're okay on that front.)

**Update**: It works if you use `id`s:

HTML:

```
<form>
  <input type='hidden' id='hdnSelectedProductPrice' value='10'>
  <input type='text' id='txtNumberOfLicense' value='2'>
  <input type='text' id='txtAmount' value='3'>
  <br><input type='button' id='theButton' value='Click Me'>
</form>
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/igebi4)

Comment: I think MS would call it a feature - it is overloaded like their document.all :)

Comment: @mplungjan: Not the only place where MS and I would use different terminology to describe their software. ;-) (*Some* of which, I hasten to point out, is quite good.)

Answer (score 0):

As T.J. mentioned we really need to see your html code, without seeing it it could be that you are looking for an elements attributes.

So lookup the element as you are already with

```
var element = document.getElementById('product');
```

Once you have the element you can query its attributes

```
var price = element.getAttribute('price');
```

Comment: I am definitely using Id's of controls and all are asp.net controls

Answer (score 0):

If its "ASP.net server control" then you will have to do it like this:

```
var originalPrice = document.getElementById('<%=hdnSelectedProductPrice.ClientID %>').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use Asp.Net **4.0** and your textbox is unique on the entirepage you can add **ClientIDMode="Static"** in attribute of your textbox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" runat="server" Width="250px" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
```